# Error when trying to use stl and decompose functions in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have made a simple time-series, i added a little noise to a sin function and tried to decompose it using the "stl" and "decompose" function in R, while my series definitely has more than 2 period and is periodic, R gives me the following error for both functions:

```
x
  [1]  1.4537365796  2.7185844368  2.8394728999  3.8926989923  4.3405508086  5.1959080871
  [7]  5.6602505790  5.4829985648  5.6357660330  4.6084976233  4.6617322922  4.0286486832
 [13]  3.3641752333  1.7408063182  0.8815147612  0.2895139342 -0.5402768515 -1.5612641107
 [19] -2.1584502547 -2.9878043526 -3.5545638149 -4.0530074199 -4.0748538612 -4.7581704662
 [25] -4.6555349052 -4.0726206240 -3.1646413472 -2.6934453823 -2.2364605277 -1.2643569882
 [31] -0.1202011946  1.1136371449  2.2504199271  3.0313528996  3.5384449109  4.5176211013
 [37]  5.4013172839  5.4252837451  5.4768196692  5.8979709077  5.6698285659  4.5133489450
 [43]  4.2702602998  3.5180837069  2.2652913344  1.1975595698  0.5412697849 -0.5966162032
 [49] -1.0827728340 -1.8488242277 -3.4118061838 -3.9009752140 -3.9102671954 -4.3486102172
 [55] -4.7481017993 -4.0097598695 -3.9078554267 -3.8070416888 -2.5968567322 -2.2567568949
 [61] -1.1423907008  0.0002492447  0.4338279080  1.2431986797  2.3216397323  3.3235925116
 [67]  4.1591487169  4.9028481873  5.4535861470  5.0579349546  5.1548777627  4.9707124992
 [73]  5.4496833187  4.4563072487  4.1301372986  2.4594352788  1.7253019929  0.6961453965
 [79]  0.4281167695 -1.3152944759 -1.8645880957 -2.5764132038 -3.7681528112 -4.3731672862
 [85] -3.9940201611 -4.5497596299 -4.9496796983 -4.1233093447 -3.7759837204 -3.3359027749
 [91] -2.3518009102 -1.7488933797 -0.7225148838  0.5395759836  1.0496249652  2.0383715782
 [97]  3.2357449979  3.8028316517  5.0346866280  5.2154265148

fit<- stl(x, t.window=15, s.window="per", robust=TRUE)
Error in stl(x, t.window = 15, s.window = "per", robust = TRUE) :series is not periodic or has less      than two periods

fit<- decompose(x,type="multiplicative")
Error in decompose(x, type = "multiplicative") :time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

Would someone help me with this problem please?

Comment: As always, Rule Number One is: Plot your data to make sure it's what you wanted it to be.

Comment: try e.g. `stl(ts(x,freq=10), t.window=15, s.window="per", robust=TRUE)`

Answer (score 18):

Isn't it obvious from the error message:

```
time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

? R's not telling you your data *aren't* periodic, just that the data you passed it have no *indication* that they are periodic.

Your time series `x` doesn't have an periodicity *from the point of view of R*. It looks like you forgot to tell, or made an error in telling, `ts()` what the periodicity is. As you don't show how `x` was created, there isn't much we can do except tell you to go back and create `x` so that it does have >=2 periods.

The point here is that on it's own, R can't deduce what the frequency of observation is per unit time. You have to tell `ts()` that information. You can do this in a number of ways:

> `frequency`: the number of observations per unit of time.
>
> `deltat`: the fraction of the sampling period between successive
>            observations; e.g., 1/12 for monthly data.  Only one of
>            `frequency` or `deltat` should be provided.

If you don't provide one of these, `ts()` uses the defaults `frequency = 1`, `deltat = 1` which would indicate a time series of one observation per unit time (one per year for example).

`stl()` requires a `"ts"` classed object - if you don't provide one, it will coerce the input data to a `"ts"` object via `as.ts()`. This function will use the defaults which I describe above.

What I think has happened here is that you didn't realise that `stl()` requires a `"ts"` class object nor that it created an inappropriate one for your data when you just supplied the vector of observations.

The solution would be to explicitly create the `"ts"` classed object via `ts()` and specify one of `frequency` or `deltat`.

E.g.

```
dat <- cumsum(rnorm(12*4))
x <- ts(dat)
stl(x, "periodic")
xx <- ts(dat, frequency = 12)
stl(xx, "periodic")
```

Here I used `frequency = 12` to indicate that there are 12 observations per unit time --- such as with monthly data.

The above gives for me

```
R> stl(x, "periodic")
Error in stl(x, "periodic") : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods

R> stl(xx, "periodic")
 Call:
 stl(x = xx, s.window = "periodic")

Components
       seasonal    trend remainder
Jan 1 -0.103529  0.55245  -0.44301
Feb 1  0.001333  0.56981   0.86135
Mar 1 -0.382075  0.58717   1.11162
Apr 1  0.010552  0.59891  -1.04966
....
```

For your data I suspect you want `frequency = 10` given the length of the time series; that would say that you have ten observations per year. If the series has more observations per year, say 12 for monthly data, but you don;t have the last two or first two months (i.e. there is no missing data, `NA`s) you just started (ended) later (earlier) in the year and hence don't have a full years worth of data at one or both ends of the series.

Comment: sorry if it was obvious, I am new in R, however, my assumption was a periodic series are regular series which contain certain frequencies in their Fourier Transform, mine had this because I created it using Sin function

Comment: Yes, but as far as the computer knows or cares, it is just a vector of numbers with no indication as the time points at which these were observed.

Comment: Good and detailed answer, but I get this error message when trying to analyze hourly data (`xxx  <- ts(x, freq=24)`). Is there, perhaps, a limit on time series length or on the number of observations per cycle? Edit: I have missing values, and I've tried using both `na.action=na.pass` and `na.action=na.exclude`.

Comment: @rbatt I can't reproduce your problem (`stl(ts(rnorm(1000), frequency = 24), "periodic")`) so some other detail matters, but looking at the code we see `if (period < 2 || n <= 2 * period)` so unless you have more than 2 "periods" in the data you'll get that error message. Does that match with your data?

Comment: @rbatt That check comes *after* the `NA`s have been removed, so it is likely that you do have more observations than 2 * 24 until the `NA`s get removed and once they're removed your data doesn't make the length threshold. It appears that the `na.action` argument doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I have about 119 periods. I just tried subsetting to the first 6 periods --- none of these values were NA, and it worked fine. I then linearly interpolated the full time series, and that also worked. Seems that `stl` does not work with `NA` values! Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: @rbatt It appears that is so; I understood you were getting the same error message, but the only way I can recreate an error is to add `NA`s and then I see a different error: `Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object`. Looking at the code it is clear that currently it can't do anything with `NA`s and will always fail, no matter what you pass the na.action argument. You might try fitting using a GAM via the **mgcv** package.

Comment: did you do `stl(..., na.action=na.exclude)` or `na.pass`? I got a similar error message to you before specifying that argument. I haven't looked at the function's code, so it's weird if that would make a difference if it doesn't looked like `na.action` does anything.